# radio input is getting frozen in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I have a radio input buttons in JSX like below.

```
import React, { Component, useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import { Link, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useDispatch, connect } from 'react-redux';

import { updateReviewAction } from '../actions/dashboard';

const EditReviewComponent = (props) => {
  const [role, setRole] = useState(null);
  const [message, setMessage] = useState('');
  const [isMessage, setIsMessage] = useState(false);
  const [jobKnowledge, setJobKnowledge] = useState('');
  const [productivity, setProductivity] = useState('');
  const [workQuality, setWorkQuality] = useState('');
  const [skills, setSkills] = useState('');

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const onUpdateReview = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    let reviewID = props.viewReviews.response._id;

    dispatch(updateReviewAction({ reviewID, jobKnowledge, productivity, workQuality, skills }));

    setMessage('');
    setIsMessage(true);
  }

  console.log(props.viewReviews);

  const onRoleChange = event => {
    setRole(event.target.value);
  }

  const onJobKnowledgeChange = event => {
    setJobKnowledge(event.target.value);
  }

  const onProductivityChange = event => {
    setProductivity(event.target.value);
  }

  const onWorkQualityChange = event => {
    setWorkQuality(event.target.value);
  }

  const onSkillsChange = event => {
    setSkills(event.target.value);
  }

  const resetMessage = () => {
    setIsMessage(false);
  }

    return (
    <div className='employees'>
      <Link to={`${props.url}`}>Close</Link>
      <h3>Edit New Employee</h3>
      <p>{(message !== '' && isMessage) ? message : ''}</p>
      <form onSubmit={onUpdateReview}>
        <div>
          <p>Job Knowledge</p>
          <label htmlFor="excellent_knowledge">
            <input
              type="radio"
              name="job_knowledge"
              id="excellent_knowledge"
              value="Excellent"
              checked={
                (props.viewReviews.hasOwnProperty('response') && props.viewReviews.response.jobKnowledge === 'Excellent')
                ? true
                : false
              }
              onChange={onJobKnowledgeChange}
              required
            />
            Excellent
          </label>
          <label htmlFor="good_knowledge">
            <input
              type="radio"
              name="job_knowledge"
              id="good_knowledge"
              value="Good"
              checked={
                (props.viewReviews.hasOwnProperty('response') && props.viewReviews.response.jobKnowledge === 'Good')
                ? true
                : false
              }
              onChange={onJobKnowledgeChange}
              required
            />
            Good
          </label>
          <label htmlFor="fair_knowledge">
            <input
              type="radio"
              name="job_knowledge"
              id="fair_knowledge"
              value="Fair"
              checked={
                (props.viewReviews.hasOwnProperty('response') && props.viewReviews.response.jobKnowledge === 'Fair')
                ? true
                : false
              }
              onChange={onJobKnowledgeChange}
              required
            />
            Fair
          </label>
          <label htmlFor="poor_knowledge">
            <input
              type="radio"
              name="job_knowledge"
              id="poor_knowledge"
              value="Poor"
              checked={
                (props.viewReviews.hasOwnProperty('response') && props.viewReviews.response.jobKnowledge === 'Poor')
                ? true
                : false
              }
              onChange={onJobKnowledgeChange}
              required
            />
            Poor
          </label>
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <p>Productivity</p>
          <label htmlFor="excellent_productivity">
            <input
              type="radio"
              name="productivity"
              id="excellent_productivity"
              value="Excellent"
              checked={
                (props.viewReviews.hasOwnProperty('response') && props.viewReviews.response.productivity === 'Excellent')
                ? true
                : false
              }
              onChange={onProductivityChange}
              required
            />
            Excellent
          </label>
          <label htmlFor="good_productivity">
            <input
              type="radio"
              name="productivity"
              id="good_productivity"
              value="Good"
              checked={
                (props.viewReviews.hasOwnProperty('response') && props.viewReviews.response.productivity === 'Good')
                ? true
                : false
              }
              onChange={onProductivityChange}
              required
            />
            Good
          </label>
          <label htmlFor="fair_productivity">
            <input
              type="radio"
              name="productivity"
              id="fair_productivity"
              value="Fair"
              checked={
                (props.viewReviews.hasOwnProperty('response') && props.viewReviews.response.productivity === 'Fair')
                ? true
                : false
              }
              onChange={onProductivityChange}
              required
            />
            Fair
          </label>
          <label htmlFor="poor_productivity">
            <input
              type="radio"
              name="productivity"
              id="poor_productivity"
              value="Poor"
              checked={
                (props.viewReviews.hasOwnProperty('response') && props.viewReviews.response.productivity === 'Poor')
                ? true
                : false
              }
              onChange={onProductivityChange}
              required
            />
            Poor
          </label>
        </div>
        <div>
          <p>Work Quality</p>
          <label htmlFor="excellent_quality">
            <input
              type="radio"
              name="quality"
              id="excellent_quality"
              value="Excellent"
              checked={
                (props.viewReviews.hasOwnProperty('response') && props.viewReviews.response.workQuality === 'Excellent')
                ? true
                : false
              }
              onChange={onWorkQualityChange}
              required
            />
            Excellent
          </label>
          <label htmlFor="good_quality">
            <input
              type="radio"
              name="quality"
              id="good_quality"
              value="Good"
              checked={
                (props.viewReviews.hasOwnProperty('response') && props.viewReviews.response.workQuality === 'Good')
                ? true
                : false
              }
              onChange={onWorkQualityChange}
              required
            />
            Good
          </label>
          <label htmlFor="fair_quality">
            <input
              type="radio"
              name="quality"
              id="fair_quality"
              value="Fair"
              checked={
                (props.viewReviews.hasOwnProperty('response') && props.viewReviews.response.workQuality === 'Fair')
                ? true
                : false
              }
              onChange={onWorkQualityChange}
              required
            />
            Fair
          </label>
          <label htmlFor="poor_quality">
            <input
              type="radio"
              name="quality"
              id="poor_quality"
              value="Poor"
              checked={
                (props.viewReviews.hasOwnProperty('response') && props.viewReviews.response.workQuality === 'Poor')
                ? true
                : false
              }
              onChange={onWorkQualityChange}
              required
            />
            Poor
          </label>
        </div>
        <div>
          <p>Technical Skills</p>
          <label htmlFor="excellent_skills">
            <input
              type="radio"
              name="skills"
              id="excellent_skills"
              value="Excellent"
              checked={
                (
                  props.viewReviews.hasOwnProperty('response') && 
                  props.viewReviews.response.skills === 'Excellent'
                )
              }
              onChange={onSkillsChange}
              required
            />
            Excellent
          </label>
          <label htmlFor="good_skills">
            <input
              type="radio"
              name="skills"
              id="good_skills"
              value="Good"
              checked={
                (
                  props.viewReviews.hasOwnProperty('response') && 
                  props.viewReviews.response.skills === 'Good'
                )
              }
              onChange={onSkillsChange}
              required
            />
            Good
          </label>
          <label htmlFor="fair_skills">
            <input
              type="radio"
              name="skills"
              id="fair_skills"
              value="Fair"
              checked={
                (props.viewReviews.hasOwnProperty('response') && props.viewReviews.response.skills === 'Fair')
              }
              onChange={onSkillsChange}
              required
            />
            Fair
          </label>
          <label htmlFor="poor_skills">
            <input
              type="radio"
              name="skills"
              id="poor_skills"
              value="Poor"
              checked={
                (props.viewReviews.hasOwnProperty('response') && props.viewReviews.response.skills === 'Poor')
              }
              onChange={onSkillsChange}
              required
            />
            Poor
          </label>
        </div>
        <div>
          <button>Update</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

const mapStateToProps = state => (state);

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(EditReviewComponent);
```

as you can see I am checking them on a condition. With this condition they are properly checked. However, when I try to click on another radio button then it does not get checked anymore. The radio buttons are frozen.

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it.

**UPDATE**

I updated the whole component. Please let me know what to do.

Comment: Can you add the definition of your onSkillsChange function?

Comment: @PhinJensen It basically set the skills in useState hook. `const onSkillsChange = event => {
    setSkills(event.target.value);
  }`

Comment: I think you should pass the state skills to your children component, in your case you pass an object. We need also to see your parent component.

Comment: I think @SoufianeBoutahlil is probably right, where the component isn't re-rendering because the state being updated isn't passed down directly, but it's hard to tell without seeing the complete component and its parent. Please add those so we can see what is going on better.

Comment: @PhinJensen I update the code and added the whole component.

Answer (score 1):

The [checked attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio#attr-checked) indicates the default value to be selected from the list of radio buttons. In your code you are trying to set `checked` from the `props` passed into the component, but this is not what you are updating when click one of the radio buttons.

When clicking a radio button, you are updating the state with these:

```
const [jobKnowledge, setJobKnowledge] = useState('');
const [productivity, setProductivity] = useState('');
const [workQuality, setWorkQuality] = useState('');
```

So, instead of determining the value of `checked` from `props`, try determining it using these state variables and I think it will work for you.

```
<input
  type="radio"
  name="job_knowledge"
  id="excellent_knowledge"
  value="Excellent"
  checked={jobKnowledge === "Excellent"}
  onChange={onJobKnowledgeChange}
  required
/>
```

PS: Based on the way you were checking the value of this variable:

```
props.viewReviews.hasOwnProperty('response') && props.viewReviews.response.jobKnowledge === 'Excellent'
```

You might want to check out [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)

Comment: You only are updating redux state when you click `Update`, which is when `props` changes. So I think you want to use local state like I have evaluate `checked` and then set the default values of your local state variables from `props`